# How to find all users who have been inactive for one month or more in Git Hub

Tags: git, github

I am not able to figure out how to get user details/information to get all users who have been inactive for one month or more.
Is there any command to get that or we have to go to gitHub UI ?

Can some one please guide me with this .
This is what i have found while searching for it .

https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.17/admin/installation/site-admin-dashboard

But i am very new to Git so not able to get the details as instructed here 
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit clunky as a full solution, but you could get the full author list with

```
git log --pretty=format:"%an" --all | sort -u
```

to compare with the list of active authors (this month) with

```
git log --pretty=format:"%an" --all --since='1 month ago' | sort -u
```

Comment: Thnaks for the Answer ..I am testing in the my environment ..I will accept that answer soon ..Thanks Again ..

Comment: The first command does not gives me the all user/members name .There are 4 members are in my project but i am getting one my name .Rest 3 names are missing .Also those 3 members are has not pushed anything into the repository .

Comment: @Anupam Yes, this solution is based on commit authoring, so if some (would-be) authors have not pushed anything yet, they won't be detected, thus not listed.